# android vision face not found ears

Tags: android, detection, face-detection, google-vision

I followed this official tutorial from Google:
https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial
but the problem is my app cannot find any ear or ear tip.

At most only 8 landmarks that can be found are
left eye,
right eye,
nose base,
left cheek,
right cheek,
left mouth,
right mouth,
bottom mouth.

I tried to use .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS) and .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE) but still not work.

I'm not sure that it is only my device or not. My testing device is Samsung Galaxy S5.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue, do you find any other solution? Or else we should use OpenCV kind of c++ library?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found solution.
This because I had cloned the example project from the link that use com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+

so, I try to change to use latest version 9.8.0, and then that work.

Comment: I have tried using the latest version 9.8.0 but seems not working for me, its still returning the above said 8 fatal features. Any other help is appreciated.

Comment: @Logunath Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Logunath I don't get the ear and ear tips of both left and right ears with latest play services version 10.2.1. Any hint ?

Comment: I moved to Google Cloud Vision framework. Their I'm getting ear points for profile face, but not for front face.